# Change the text color of a table view cell using rgba

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

How do I change the text color of a tableview cell using rgba? I have the following code which is not working. The text color is turning to white when it should be a dark brown.

```
cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 100, green: 60, blue: 60, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Divide the red, green and blue values by 256. They are supposed to be 0.0 - 1.0

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

```
cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 60/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

But for a more Xcode 10 way:

1. Go to the assets folder in your project
2. Right-click in the area that already has "AppIcon" (outline view) and pick "New Color Set"
3. Click on the color it should be a white box in the middle of the screen
4. On the right in the utilities area in the "Color" section click on the "Input Method" drop down and select "8-bit (0-255)"
5. Now just put in your values i.e. 100, 60, 60, 100%

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much for your help